# border bottom changing on press flatlist item in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm new in react native and i need your help

i want to give border-bottom to pressed item of horizontal flatlist and border-bottom of Previous item disappear,
now i can give border to new pressed item but i cant remove previous item border
how can i achive this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiyRR.png)

these are my Category_style code

```
state = {
        isModalVisible: false,
        Index : 0
    }

_toggleModal = (index) => {
    this.setState({isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible});
    this.setState({Index : index});
}

renderProduct(item) {
    return <Sub_Categories_FlatList_style name={item.title} icon={item.icon}/>
}

renderSeparator = () => (
    <View
        style={{
            backgroundColor: '#d2d2d2',
            height: 0.5,
        }}
    />
)

render() {
    const {title, index} = this.props;
    return (
<View style={pStyles.container}>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._toggleModal(index)}
                              style={(index === this.state.Index) ? pStyles.border_bottom : pStyles.no_border_bottom}>
                <Text style={pStyles.title}>{title}</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible} animationType={'slide'}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._toggleModal(index)} style={pStyles.T_opacity}
                                  activeOpacity={.7}>
                    <Image source={require('./../pictures/x_icon.png')}
                           style={pStyles.close_image}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={pStyles.in_modal_view}>
                    <Text style={pStyles.modal_header_text}>{title}</Text>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.props.subCategory}
                        renderItem={({item}) => this.renderProduct(item)}
                        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}/>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
```

and these are my Category code

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#4caf50'
    },
    headerTitle: <Text style={Category_in_style.headerTitleStyle}>Category</Text>
}

renderCategory(item, index) {
    return <Category_style title={item.title} index={index} subCategory={item.sub_category}/>

}

renderProduct(item) {
    return <Product_style image={item.imageUrl} title={item.title} price={item.price}/>
}

render() {
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                <FlatList style={styles.first_flat}
                          horizontal
                          data={this.state.main_categories}
                          renderItem={({item, index})=> this.renderCategory(item, index)}
                          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}/>
                <PTRView style={{backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1'}}>
                    <FlatList style={[{marginTop: 10}, {marginBottom: 50}]}
                              data={this.state.articles}
                              renderItem={({item}) => this.renderProduct(item)}
                              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                              numColumns={2}/>
                </PTRView>
            </View>
```

Comment: after learning more react native and es6 i realized that we can do this by Reflection in es6
that's too easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be multiple ways of doing this but I prefer having the parent decide which component is clicked.

So what I suggest is in your renderProduct the item object also has an index which you can pass to your Sub_Categories_FlatList_style and also pass a function to it which basically updates a variable whenever the item is clicked.

Then when you render the list item simply check if it's index matches the currently selected index and then style it accordingly.

Sorry if this seems a bit vague but I'm eyeballing this since I'm at work but I'll be more than happy to answer any follow ups.